# Converting a System.Drawing.Point to JSON. How can I convert 'X' and 'Y' to 'x' and 'y'?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I am trying to adhere to the naming conventions in JavaScript as well as in C#. This leads to interesting issues when passing JSONized data back and forth. When I access an x/y coordinate client-side I expect the property to be lowercase, but server-side it is uppercase.

Observe:

```
public class ComponentDiagramPolygon
{
    public List<System.Drawing.Point> Vertices { get; set; }

    public ComponentDiagramPolygon()
    {
        Vertices = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();
    }
}

public JsonResult VerticesToJsonPolygon(int componentID)
{
    PlanViewComponent planViewComponent = PlanViewServices.GetComponentsForPlanView(componentID, SessionManager.Default.User.UserName, "image/png");
    ComponentDiagram componentDiagram = new ComponentDiagram();

    componentDiagram.LoadComponent(planViewComponent, Guid.NewGuid());

    List<ComponentDiagramPolygon> polygons = new List<ComponentDiagramPolygon>();

    if (componentDiagram.ComponentVertices.Any())
    {
        ComponentDiagramPolygon polygon = new ComponentDiagramPolygon();
        componentDiagram.ComponentVertices.ForEach(vertice => polygon.Vertices.Add(vertice));
        polygons.Add(polygon);
    }

    return Json(polygons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I understand that if I am able to use the C# attribute 'JsonProperty' to customize naming conventions. Yet, as far as I can tell, this is only applicable to classes which I am owner of.

How may I change System.Drawing.Point's  properties when passing back to the client?

Comment: If you are using `JsonProperty` then you are using JSON.NET, and not the stock `JavaScriptSerializer`; is that so?

Comment: Yes. The reference to JSON.NET is already included into the project -- I just have not utilized it (yet) in this scenario.

Comment: This seems similar to this question from a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247478/pascal-case-dynamic-properties-with-json-net/9247705#9247705.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Thank you. I have read that post now -- it seems to imply that best practice says to leave the capitalization alone. Is that correct?

Comment: I'd say leave it alone. While I completely understand your motivation, you can also argue that since it's a representation the C# model, it should stay true to that. I.e. it's not so much that that the client-side receives JSON data, but rather that it receives _C# data_. That it happens to be JSON is largely irrelevant, as it could just as easily be XML or some binary format. Just pretend you're accessing the C# data directly, and ignore the specifics of how it's transmitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cheat, by projecting into a new anonymous type:

```
var projected = polygons.Select(p => new { Vertices = p.Vertices.Select(v => new { x = v.X, y = v.Y }) });

return Json(projected, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about writing your own Json.NET based converter:

```
public class NJsonResult : ActionResult
{
    private object _obj { get; set; }

    public NJsonResult(object obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_obj, 
                                            Formatting.Indented,
                                            new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                {
                                                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                                                }));
    }
}
```

This will just work for your entire application, without properties renaming necessity (to lowercase) in your classes in following way: `return Json(new { x = ..., y = ...});`

And below is the usage example in controller action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public virtual NJsonResult GetData()
{
    var data = ...
    return new NJsonResult(data);
}
```